# Adding .wav and .png/.jpg files to a GUI

Tags: java

I have a created a simple tic tac toe GUI GAME. I want to extend it by changing what is displayed on the buttons from just text "X" and "O" to fancy graphic "X" and "O" (by providing jpg or png files) and  also add sounds using .wav files.

This is my code for my game: (It works perfectly.. I just need help with the extensions.. Thanks)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TicTacToeGUI implements ActionListener
{
   //Class constants
   private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 300;
   private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;
   private static final int TEXT_WIDTH = 30;

   private static final String PLAYER_X = "X"; // player using "X"
   private static final String PLAYER_O = "O"; // player using "O"
   private static final String EMPTY = "";  // empty cell
   private static final String TIE = "T"; // game ended in a tie

   private String player;   // current player (PLAYER_X or PLAYER_O)

   private String winner;   // winner: PLAYER_X, PLAYER_O, TIE, EMPTY = in progress

   private int numFreeSquares; // number of squares still free

   private JMenuItem resetItem; // reset board

   private JMenuItem quitItem; // quit

   private JLabel gameText; // current message

   private JButton board[][]; // 3x3 array of JButtons

   private JFrame window = new JFrame("TIC-TAC-TOE"); 



    /**
       * Constructs a new Tic-Tac-Toe GUI board
       */

   public TicTacToeGUI()
   {
       setUpGUI(); // set up GUI
       setFields(); // set up other fields   
   }



  /**
   * Set up the non-GUI fields
   *
   */
   private void setFields() 
   {
       winner = EMPTY;
       numFreeSquares = 9;
       player = PLAYER_X;
   }

   /**
   * reset the game so we can start again.
   *
   */
   private void resetGame() 
   {
       // reset board
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           {
               board[i][j].setText(EMPTY);
               board[i][j].setEnabled(true);
           }
       }
       gameText.setText("Game in Progress: X's turn");
       // reset other fields
       setFields();
    }



 /**
   * Action Performed (from actionListener Interface).
   * (This method is executed when a button is selected.)
   *
   * @param the action event
   */

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
       // see if it's a menu item
       if(e.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem) 
       {
           JMenuItem select = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
           if (select==resetItem)
           { 
               resetGame();// reset
               return;
           }
           System.exit(0);   // must be quit
       }

       // it must be a button
       JButton chose = (JButton) e.getSource();  // set chose to the button clicked
       chose.setText(player);     // set its text to the player's mark
       chose.setEnabled(false);   // disable button (can't choose it now)
       numFreeSquares--;

       //see if game is over 
       if(haveWinner(chose))
       {
           winner = player; // must be the player who just went
       }
       else if(numFreeSquares==0)
       {
           winner = TIE; // board is full so it's a tie 
       }

       // if have winner stop the game
       if (winner!=EMPTY) 
       {
           disableAll(); // disable all buttons
           // print winner
           String s = "Game over: ";
           if (winner == PLAYER_X) 
           {
               s += "X wins";
           } 
           else if (winner == PLAYER_O) 
           {
               s += "O wins";
           } 
           else if (winner == TIE) 
           {
               s += "Tied game";
           }   
           gameText.setText(s);
       } 
       else
       {
           // change to other player (game continues)
           if (player==PLAYER_X)
           {
               player=PLAYER_O;
               gameText.setText("Game in progress: O's turn");
           } 
           else
           {
               player=PLAYER_X;
               gameText.setText("Game in progress: X's turn");
           }
       }
   }


   /**
    * Returns true if filling the given square gives us a winner, and false
    * otherwise.
    *
    * @param Square just filled
    * 
    * @return true if we have a winner, false otherwise
    */
   private boolean haveWinner(JButton c) 
   {
       // unless at least 5 squares have been filled, we don't need to go any further
       // (the earliest we can have a winner is after player X's 3rd move).
       if(numFreeSquares>4) 
       {
           return false;
       }

       // find the square that was selected
       int row=0, col=0;

       outerloop: // a label to allow us to break out of both loops
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           {
              if (c==board[i][j])
              { 
                  // object identity
                  row = i;
                  col = j;  //  row, col represent the chosen square
                  break outerloop; // break out of both loops
              }    
           }
       }

       // check row "row"
       if( board[row][0].getText().equals(board[row][1].getText()) && board[row][0].getText().equals(board[row][2].getText()) )
       {
           return true;
       }

       // check column "col"
       if (board[0][col].getText().equals(board[1][col].getText()) &&board[0][col].getText().equals(board[2][col].getText()) ) 
       {
           return true;
       }

       // if row=col check one diagonal
       if (row == col)
       {
          if( board[0][0].getText().equals(board[1][1].getText()) && board[0][0].getText().equals(board[2][2].getText()) ) 
          {
              return true;
          }
       }

       // if row=2-col check other diagonal
       if (row == 2-col)
       {
          if( board[0][2].getText().equals(board[1][1].getText()) && board[0][2].getText().equals(board[2][0].getText()) )
          {
              return true;
          }
       }

       // no winner yet
       return false;
   }


   /**
   * Disables all buttons (game over)
   */
   private void disableAll()
   {
       if (numFreeSquares==0) 
       {
           return; // nothing to do
       }

       int i, j;
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
              board[i][j].setEnabled(false);
           }
       }
   }

   /**
   * Set up the GUI
   *
   */
   private void setUpGUI()
   {

        // for control keys
        final int SHORTCUT_MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask(); 

        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // set up the menu bar and menu
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        window.setJMenuBar(menubar); // add menu bar to our frame

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Game"); // create a menu called "Game"
        menubar.add(fileMenu); // and add to our menu bar

        resetItem = new JMenuItem("Reset"); // create a menu item called "Reset"
        fileMenu.add(resetItem); // and add to our menu (can also use ctrl-R:)
        resetItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, SHORTCUT_MASK));
        resetItem.addActionListener(this); 

        quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit"); // create a menu item called "Quit"
        fileMenu.add(quitItem); // and add to our menu (can also use ctrl-Q:)
        quitItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, SHORTCUT_MASK));
        quitItem.addActionListener(this);

        window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // default so not required

        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        window.getContentPane().add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        gameText = new JLabel("Game in Progress: X's turn");
        window.getContentPane().add(gameText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // create JButtons, add to window, and action listener
        board = new JButton[3][3];
        Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 24);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
           for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
           {
              board[i][j] = new JButton(EMPTY);
              board[i][j].setFont(font);
              gamePanel.add(board[i][j]);
              board[i][j].addActionListener(this);
           }
        }

        window.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign an image to a JButton you can either use constructor or a method below:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("D:\\icon.png"));  

setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\icon.png"));
```

Of course provide your own file path.

To play some .wav sounds you can use this:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class MusicPlayer {

    private Clip clip;

    public void play() {

            try {
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("D:\\sound.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```